# Getting a GET error in console - 404 not found for wp-json

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, json

I am trying to use ajax for a Load more posts button on a Custom Post Type

In my functions file I have this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'custom_api_get_news');
function custom_api_get_news(){
  register_rest_route( 'news', '/news', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'custom_api_get_news_callback'
  ));
}

function custom_api_get_news_callback($request){
    $posts_data = array();
    $paged = $request->get_param('page');
    $paged = (isset($paged) || !(empty($paged))) ? $paged : 1;
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'status' => 'published',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged
    ));

    foreach($posts as $post){
        $id = $post->ID;
        $post_thumbnail = (has_post_thumbnail($id)) ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id) : null;
        $post_cat = get_the_category($id);

        $posts_data[] = (object)array(
            'id' => $id,
            'slug' => $post->post_name,
            'type' => $post->post_type,
            'title' => $post->post_title,
            'featured_img_src' => $post_thumbnail,
            'category' => $post_cat[0]->cat_name
        );
    }
    return $posts_data;
}
```

In my js file I have:

```
$('#loadButton').click(function() {
let pull_page = 1;
let jsonFlag = true;

if(jsonFlag) {
    jsonFlag = false;
    pull_page++;

    $.getJSON("/wp-json/news/all-posts?page=" + pull_page, function(data){
        if(data.length){
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                const arr = $.map(val, function(el) {
                    return el
                });
                const post_url = arr[1];
                const post_title = arr[3];
                const post_img = arr[4];
                const post_cat = arr[5];
                const post_class = (class_counter == 2) ? 'post adjust' : 'post';

                let item_string = '<div class="news__holder">' + post_img + '</div>';
                items.push(item_string);
            });
            if(data.length >= 6){

                $("#news-archive").append(items);
            } else {
                $("#news-archive").append(items);
                $("#load-more").hide();
            }
        } else {
            $("#load-more").hide();
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        if(data.length){
            jsonFlag = true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And on the archive page:

```
<?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'news',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'order_by' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $news = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $news->have_posts() ) :
     ?>

         <section id="news-archive" class="news">
            <?php while( $news->have_posts() ): $news->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="news__holder">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <p class="news__holder__date"><?php the_date(); ?></p>
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
         </section>
         <?php
         if($news->post_count < 6) {

         } else {
          ?>
         <section id="load-more" class="load-more">
             <div class="load-more__holder">
                <button id="loadButton"  type="button" name="button">Load More Posts</button>
             </div>

         </section>

     <?php } ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

The problem I am having is when I click on the Load More button I am getting an error in the console of **GET http://localhost:8888/una/wp-json/news/all-posts?page=2 404 (Not Found)**

I am not sure if this matters but I had seen on a few other posts some people having trouble with this part but mine is returning the json fine if you go to http://localhost:8888/una/wp-json/news -- Below is what is shown at this url. Any ideas on how to solve this error?

```
 {"namespace":"news","routes":{"\/news":{"namespace":"news","methods":["GET"],"endpoints":[{"methods":["GET"],"args":{"namespace":{"required":false,"default":"news"},"context":{"required":false,"default":"view"}}}],"_links":{"self":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/una\/wp-json\/news"}},"\/news\/news":{"namespace":"news","methods":["GET"],"endpoints":[{"methods":["GET"],"args":[]}],"_links":{"self":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/una\/wp-json\/news\/news"}}},"_links":{"up":[{"href":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/una\/wp-json\/"}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're using is not the URL that you've registered.

This code:

```
register_rest_route( 'news', '/news', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'custom_api_get_news_callback'
));
```

Registers this URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/una/wp-json/news/news
```

But you're sending requests to

```
http://localhost:8888/una/wp-json/news/all-posts
```

Nowhere in your code have you defined an `all-posts` endpoint.

You either need to change `/news` in `register_rest_route()` to `/all-posts`, or the `/all-posts` in your URL to `/news`. They need to be the same.

Comment: Thanks all working now, I knew it was something to do with the URL but I had been messing around it with it that long I couldn't see for looking!